# Check if Object inside an ArrayList have same ID value before insert into ArrayList

Tags: java, google-maps, android-studio, arraylist

Hey guys I have this ArrayList

```
public static List<JSONObject> markerList = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
```

I put a JSONObject inside it with for (loop)
With an ID from the server with some info
And a marker id (Google Maps..)

How can I check if this object inside the array have specific id so I don't insert it anymore
Because this object will have different values like Latitude and longitude and marker id but will have the same driver id with all duplicated objects inside the ArrayList this is really playing my mind how can I check it I tried to google everywhere any help guys <3

```
public static List<JSONObject> markerList = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
public static void CreateMarker(JSONArray arrayList){
    try {
        Marker marker;
        for (int counter = 0; counter < arrayList.length(); counter++) {
            JSONObject json=arrayList.getJSONObject(counter);
            int id = json.getInt("id");
            int is_active = json.getInt("is_active");
            double latitude = json.getDouble("latitude");
            double longitude = json.getDouble("longitude");

                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                        .title(String.valueOf(id))
                        .flat(true)
                        .anchor(0.5f, 1.0f)
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.car_marker_dark));
                marker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                Log.e("MarkerList", "Marker id '" + marker.getId() + "' added to list.");
                Log.e("MarkerList", String.valueOf(markerList));
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                jsonObject.put("id",id);
                jsonObject.put("is_active",is_active);
                jsonObject.put("latitude",latitude);
                jsonObject.put("longitude",longitude);
                jsonObject.put("Marker",marker);
                markerList.add(jsonObject);

        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `==` instead of `.equals()`. `==` checks if two object are the same object, and does not check if they have the same content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution to your problem could be using a `HashMap` instead of an `ArrayList` with the key being the id and the value being the JSONObject. This way, you can check if the `HashMap` already contains your key before inserting it.

Comment: A Really Really nice way bro I have some questions If you can, of course, <3, Bro If I wanted to edit on a key inside the HashMap how can I do it is it just put the new values and that's all (But I need the marker id, not a new one)? and what are the difference in the performance ArrayList and hashMap and limitations of it if it's limited by the number of keys

Comment: Glad I could help! If you wanted to edit the JSON object you could just replace it with the corresponding id. The difference in performance between an ArrayList and a HashMap is that finding an element in a HashMap takes O(1) time, finding an element from an ArrayList can take up to O(n) time if you are not searching by index. As for limitations, I think a valid one is that, if you get all the values from the map, it doesn't ensure that they will be returned in the same order they were inserted. Other than that, I think it perfectly fits your use case.